# Error: cannot find module '${process.cwd()}/dist/server' when deploying Angular Universal SSR app to Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I followed the instructions on https://fireship.io/lessons/angular-universal-firebase/ to deploy an Angular Universal SSR application with Firebase Cloud Functions. However, on the final step, I ran into this error.

[image]

which is strange considering I am already calling Firebase Serve from inside the function subdirectory. I need this to deploy properly and test. I know through previous using node/dist server that SSR is indeed working. My firebase.json, package.json, index.ts, and cp-angular.js files are identical to the steps shown in Fireship.io's example. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `instead of` in the functions/src/index.ts file, that's why you are getting this error. I would recommend you to copy the code directly from git, or to compare it to the file over [here](https://github.com/fireship-io/159-angular-universal-cloud-functions).

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I needed.